# mysql parameter set null to database by c#

Tags: c#, mysql

I have an method like below in C# and i'm gonna to parameterize my query but name field get null value in  database .testTable(id,name) and id is auto increament.mysql ver is 5.6

```
   private void buttonTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

      string query = "insert into testdb.testTable(name) VALUES (@name) ;";
        MySqlConnection conDataBase = new MySqlConnection(myfunctions.ConnString);
         conDataBase.Open();
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, conDataBase);

        try
        {
            cmd.Connection = conDataBase;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name","John");

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)

        { MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); }
    }
```

Comment: use ?name instead for @name.

Comment: Yah .Thank you .working with ?name

Answer (score 0):

try this in place of varchar,50 enter your dbtype

```
string query = "insert into testdb.testTable(name) VALUES(_name) ;";
```

and

```
        cmd.Connection = conDataBase;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("_name", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = "John";

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
command.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.VarChar,50);
command.Parameters["@name"].Value = "john";
```